# multiple section

Tags: custom-post-types

I use ACF plugin to add custom post type . but there is a three diffrent sections in my code 
In first add the main title like our service and in second secton add service items and in third there is a read more button for more service items. How can i solve this. my service items is successfully dynamic but main title and readmore button cant understand how can make dynamic. My code is there :

### /assets/images/head.png" alt="#"/> Our Services

'services',);

                    $service_query = new WP_Query( $ser );

                    if(have_posts() ) : while($service_query->have_posts() ) : $service_query->the_post();
                ?>
               

                  
                     */assets/images/thr.png" alt="#"/>-->*

Read More

[image]

Comment: ACF doesn't create custom post types, it creates custom fields. Can you clarify your question a bit? What is it you mean by section, service items, etc, and why are you using WP_Query?

Comment: I used the ACF plugin and Custom post type ui plugin. I craete a custom post through the Custom post type ui plugin . I attach a file screenshort

Answer (score 0):

The questions seem quite confusing but hope this helps you.

- If you want to render the main title - use `<?php get_the_title();
  ?>`this help you render the post title.
- For rendering the post link (permalink) - use `<?php echo
  get_permalink($post->ID);?>`
- For rendering fiedls created through ACF use - `<?php echo
  the_field('slug_of field');?>`